# Receive http requests in neutralinojs server

Tags: javascript, jquery, request, neutralinojs

is there a way to receive external http requests in neutralino js (server)?

I can set a fix port in the config file (e.g. `5050`), so I have a static target (e.g.: `http://localhost:5050`). If I send a http request to that location I get the status `200` , so the server is accessible. But how can I set an endpoint (e.g.: `http://localhost:5050/myEndoint`) and handle the incoming request in neutralinojs?

Comment: You can send a request but there is no way to get the request headers and other stuff from our javascript code.